# Как объяснить  выбор О/Е после Ц  и нужно ли это делать ?

Tags: орфография

Интересно, что исходное правило звучит довольно просто: В СУФФИКСАХ И ОКОНЧАНИЯХ различных частей речи после шипящих и Ц пишется О под ударением и Е без ударения. Но потом появляется желание правило обобщить, сказать, что пишется В КОРНЕ, учесть все исключения, которые никак не объясняются (как, впрочем и само правило), и тогда оно перестает быть простым, и понятным, и легко запоминающимся.

Кроме того,  появляется "корыто - корытцо", где так и хочется написать О после Ц. Выбор дЕревце - деревцО также начинает вызывать сомнения (и даже протест) у обычных пользователей русского языка.  В результате русская система письма (очень стройная и логичная) становится предметом критики, а также вызывает желание ее реформировать.

И вопрос: Как объяснить правило "Выбор О/Е после Ц", и надо ли это делать, и почему никто этого не делает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грот как раз убрал все исключения, убрал неразбериху типа лице-лицо,Карташев-Карташов,танцовать-танцевать, сделал правило понятным. Придумывать что-то новое-вносить сложности, а не чёткость.

История написаний гласных после шипящих и ц связана с влиянием морфологических написаний на графику.

Возможность написания е или о после шипящих (а также и после ц) появилась в связи с законом перехода /э/ в /о/ после мягких согласных под ударением (в том числе и после когда-то мягких /ж/, /ш/ и /ц/). Этимологическое /э/, перешедшее под ударением в /о/, после шипящих и /ц/, ввиду их непарности по мягкости-твердости, могло быть и обозначено (по выговору) буквой о. Существующее сейчас распределение в написании е и о после шипящих, а также после ц сложилось в основном стихийно на основе подравнивания написания одной морфемы к другой: морфемы с шипящими и ц "равнялись" на морфемы с нешипящими.

После ц в русском языке никогда не следуют ни личные глагольные окончания первого спряжения, ни причастный суффикс -енн-(-ен-), т.е. никогда не следуют такие продуктивные морфемы, которые, употребляясь после других согласных, имеют в своем составе е. Таким образом, после ц при передаче на письме ударного /о/, этимологически восходящего к /э/, не было необходимости сохранить графическое е, что существует прежде всего при написании глагольных окончаний первого спряжения и суффикса страдательных причастий прошедшего времени.
Глагольные формы с наличием ц в основе ограничиваются лишь словами типа танцевать, гарцевать, вальцевать и т.п.(к тому же малочисленными). Личные глагольные формы их оканчиваются на -цую, -цуешь, а страдательные причастия прошедшего времени от этих глаголов не образуются.

При передаче на письме /о/, этимологически восходящего к /э/, после ц наблюдалась та же морфологическая тенденция, какую мы наблюдаем при складывающемся обычае писать е/о после шипящих.

После ц закреплялось написание о при произнесении /о/ в ударных окончаниях имен существительных, ибо для имен существительных окончания с о являются сильной графической моделью: лицо́, как село́, про́со (форма лицо́ - наряду с лице́ - указывается уже в "Российской грамматике" Ломоносова1); кольцо́м, как село́м, про́сом; огурцо́в, как зубо́в, оре́хов, но безударные окончания пишутся с е: полоте́нце, как по́ле, полоте́нцем, как по́лем; па́льцев, как злоде́ев.
Закрепилось написание о после ц в суффиксе -овск-: отцо́вский, спецóвский и т.п., так как именно вариант с о является графически сильным - после других твердых согласных он употребляется как под ударением: бесо́вский, черто́вский, старико́вский, так и без ударения: де́довский, ма́ртовский, рабко́ровский. Вариант -ёвск-, встречающийся в единичных случаях после мягких согласных (кремлёвский), является графически вынужденным.
Окончания с графическим о, передающим звук /о/, после ц многочисленны (кольцо́, яйцо́, крыльцо́ и т.д.), так как многочисленны именные основы на ц. Поэтому после ц легче, чем после шипящих, установить единое графическое о для обозначения ударного /о/ и в малочисленных суффиксальных морфемах слов типа вальцо́вка, танцо́р, и в корневой морфеме с /о/: цо́кот.

http://bibl.tikva.ru/base/B952/B952Part17-85.php

Comment: >>>Грот как раз убрал все исключения,   
  
Ну значит, я запомнил "с точностью до наоборот".
Хотя по вашему тексту и не скажешь, что речь идет о каком-то "упрощении".)))

Comment: Людмила, большое спасибо за интересную информацию о становлении русской орфографии.  Как я поняла, проблема О/Е после шипящих возникла в 19 веке, когда чередование Е/Ё после МЯГКИХ согласных стало отражаться на письме .  Такое же явление наблюдалось и ДЛЯ ШИПЯЩИХ  и Ц, но после твердых Ж, Ш, Ц звук О в ударной позиции стал обозначаться  буквой О (причем в сущ., прил.  и нар. после Ж,Ш,Ц, а после Ц  - во всех формах, включая  суффиксы глаголов, по аналогии с существующей графической моделью для этих слов).

Comment: Также спасибо behemothus за  указанный учебник (по возможности непременно с ним ознакомлюсь).

Answer (score 2):

**Грот** писал, что  ***о*** ставится после ***ц*** всякий раз, **когда на этот слог падает ударение**, напр. *лицо, кольцом, купцов.*

И далее:

*"В противном случае, т. е. **при отсутствии над этим слогом ударения**, пишут **е**, напр. **зеркальце, перцем, иностранцев, улицею, лицевать.** Только начертание неопред. наклонения глаголов: **танцовать, гарцовать** и **шпринцовать** составляет исключение из этого правила.*

*Собственно говоря, в неударяемых слогах: **це, цем, цев, цею**, также слышится не **е**, а средний звук между **а** и **о**, и потому тут равным образом можно бы писать **о**, что некоторые и делают...*

*Так как однакоже установленное обычаем различие в употреблении **о** и **е** после **ц** имеет свою полезную сторону, именно **служит указанием относительно ударения**, то лучше сохранить это двоякое написание".*

Comment: Как вы объясняете "нестандартное" написание трёх глаголов? Это продолжалось почему-то очень долго.

Comment: Слава, спасибо за ответ и цитату из Грота. Судя по ее содержанию, Грот не видит особой необходимости в написании Е после Ц.  Однако, если это сложилось исторически, то можно оставить Е: все равно редуцированный звук не очень ясен, да еще безударный слог можно обозначить. Мне такой подход не кажется убедительным – преимущества сомнительные, в то время как   особое правило для шипящих и Ц доставляет больше хлопот.

Comment: Как вы объясняете "нестандартное" написание трёх глаголов? Это продолжалось почему-то очень долго.
Дерзкий Grantum 
===
К сожалению, никак не объясняю. Знаний недостаточно. Могу только предположить, что на написание этих глаголов оказало влияние их имевшееся в то время произношение. Плюс наличие родственных слов:  танцОр, танцОвщик, гарцОвник, шпринцОвка...

Да и не уверен в том, что только эти три глагола писались в 19-м веке с "-цовать": возможно, Грот просто не указал на другие. У Ушакова ведь есть и вальцОвать, и глянцОвать...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и цитату из Грота. Судя по ее содержанию, Грот не видит особой необходимости в написании Е после Ц.
Vera 
===
А по-моему, как раз видит. И ратует за то, чтобы не писалось О в безударных слогах: "различие в употреблении О и Е после Ц имеет свою полезную сторону, именно служит указанием относительно ударения".

Comment: Я и говорю: сомнительная полезность "указания относительно ударения", и особое правило с не очень понятным для пользователей назначением. Тем не менее я считаю это правило в орфографии совершенно необходимым и очень важным, просто ему  нужно дать простое и понятное объяснение. Объяснения Грота в этом отрывке недостаточно, но, может быть, у него есть еще что-нибудь?

Comment: Спасиб за формулировку из Грота. Ну собственно, она не слишком отличается от современной. Мне казалось, что там куда все путанее было...  
Но тогда получается, что вообще спору нет...

Answer (score 1):

> Как объяснить правило "Выбор О/Е после Ц", и надо ли это делать, и почему никто этого не делает?

Что именно тут надо объяснять-то? Сформулировали (slava1947) вполне грамотно. 
***Под ударением пишется так, как слышится. Без ударения - всегда Е.***

Если написано (современным автором) "корытцо", то значит, он или не знает правила, или произносит с ударением на окончании.

Более ранние колебания в написании объясняются невыработанностью единых правил (если не ошибаюсь, Грот допускал оба написания - по какому-то более хитрому правилу), и меньшей степенью редукции безударного О в подобных случаях по офроэпическим нормам того времени.

А если интересует почему вообще возникла такая ситуация - то это уже история языка. Объяснять её надо только тем, кому это интересно... Если очень кратко, О и Э в какой-то мере дополняли и заменяли друг друга в разных ситуациях на всем протяжении истории русского и даже общеславянского языка. Почти во всех случаях проблема "О/Е" (практическая или чисто академическая) возникает на месте исторического (Й)Э. Это легко проследить, путем сравнения со старославянским или,  например, с современным польским.

Comment: ВО-ПЕРВЫХ, в приведенных правилах  можно увидеть смешение разных орфограмм: 1) проверяемые гласные в корне (цокотать – цокот); 2) непроверяемые гласные в корне  (герцог, скерцо); 3) выбор О/Е в суффиксах и окончаниях. Именно этот «винегрет» делает правило неудобным для использования. ВО-ВТОРЫХ, современная орфография должна ориентироваться на современное состояние языка. Когда-то Ж, Ш, Ц были мягкими, но они уже давно твердые, и стоит ли сохранять для них особые правила? А если это важно, то почему? Хорошо бы получить краткий и понятный каждому школьнику ответ.

Comment: И В ТРЕТЬИХ, может быть, Грот был прав, связывая  выбор О/Е с редукцией гласных. Опять же здесь не помешает очень короткое и очень понятное  для всех объяснение.

Comment: >непроверяемые гласные в корне (герцог, скерцо); 
Мы же про русские слова все-таки. А заимствования они почти всегда "проверяются" только по словарю.

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю этой формулировки Грота,  мне просто нравится сама идея о том, что выбор О/Е связан с особой редукцией гласных после шипящих и Ц.